# Unknown connector type

Tags: connector

I'm using this connector in designing rgb LED strip for Christmas decoration lights string. I need fifty more of this but don't know how to order it because I don't know what it is called.

[image]
[image]

Thirty cm of rgb strip is inserted inside polyurethene tube which is cut to the same length. The second problem is the 30cm tube is arced. Is there any easy way to straighten these? The purpose of the tube is to stiff the strip and seal it from water.

Pls help.

Comment: Searching for "HRS connectors" brings up a few useful-looking links.

Comment: My first thought on seeing HRS was Hirose, quick product search shows little but maybe worth a closer look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connector appears to be an "IDC" Insulation Displacement Contact type. Where the thru-wires are laid into a sharp fork-shape contact and then pressed into it with a separate back-piece. The sharp fork cuts through the wire insulation and makes contact with the wire. A quick check (and several decades of experience) show that the 1x4 configuration exactly as your photo shows is an uncommon type.  You may be searching for a while to find identical replacements.

Those connectors typically are NOT water tight, but they are probably low voltage, so not as important. Note that the PITCH (distance between pins) is CRITICAL. There may be very similar connectors with slightly different pitches but they are NOT interchangeable.  It is critical that you measure the pitch of the pins in order to find compatible connectors.

Your bent tubes may be able to be straightened by careful, gentle heating. Perhaps from a few minutes in an oven set for the lowest temperature or a hair-dryer, etc.

Comment: The pitch is 2.54mm and yes, they are not water tight, so I use a layer of thick grease before clamping on the wires. Operating voltage is dc12V at 3amp max. This is not going to be submerged but possible exposure to rain.